# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/sh": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux

i wanted to perform rename and delete function and the environment is LINUX.
This is the code which I'm using,

```
String[] command_ary = { "/usr/bin/sh", "-c", command };
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec( command_ary );
```

But Im getting the following error message,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/sh": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help me.
Thank-You

Comment: Can you try running `echo $SHELL` or `whereis sh` on your command line?

Comment: BTW You might find your command runs without a shell, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: actually previously we were using UNIX and now moved to LINUX. I will try using /bin/sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception says, there's no file `/usr/bin/sh` on your system. If you're looking for the Bourne shell, that's `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score -2):

```java
public void run() {
        //log.info("taskDao:{},concurrentHashSet:{},id:{},shellName:{},shellDate:{}", taskDao, concurrentHashSet, id, shellName, shellDate);
        log.info("concurrentHashSet:{},param:{}", concurrentHashSet, param);

        int exeState = 99999;
        // ssh跳转到其他机器去执行脚本,you can add "ssh rd@g1-jg-hadoop-01 \"source ~/.bash_profile ; bash -x %s %s\"" instead of command
        String command = "source ~/.bash_profile ; bash -x %s %s";
        String commandF = String.format(command, param.getShellName(), param.getRecallDate());
        String[] cmdArr = {"/bin/sh", "-c", commandF};
        long taskId = param.getTaskId();

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = runtime.exec(cmdArr);
            InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            log.info("exe task thread param:{},commandF:{},execute shell info:{}", param, commandF, sb.toString());
            exeState = process.waitFor();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            log.error("execute shell error,exeState:{},command:{}", exeState, commandF,e);
        } finally {
            log.info("execute shell state:{}", exeState);
            // 从set中删除 更新表状态 多张表一个脚本，会有问题，其中状态覆盖
            if (exeState == 0) {
                // 执行成功
                taskDao.updateStateByPrimaryKey(taskId, (short) 30, new Date());
                // 邮件参数
                param.setState(30);

                String mailBody = SendMailUtil.beautyMailHtmlLayout(param);
                String mailToAddress = param.getMailToUser();
                String mailTitle = param.getMailContentTitle();
                try {
                    SendMailUtil.sendMail(mailToAddress, mailTitle, mailBody);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (exeState != 0) {
                // 执行失败
                taskDao.updateStateByPrimaryKey(taskId, (short) 40, new Date());

                // 邮件参数
                param.setState(40);

                String mailBody = SendMailUtil.beautyMailHtmlLayout(param);
                String mailToAddress = param.getMailToUser();
                try {
                    SendMailUtil.sendMail(mailToAddress, "回溯任务", mailBody);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ExecuteTaskModel taskModel = new ExecuteTaskModel();
            taskModel.setId(taskId);
            log.info("remove task in thread,id:{}", taskId);
            boolean remove;
            if (concurrentHashSet.contains(taskModel)) {
                remove = concurrentHashSet.remove(taskModel);
            }
            log.info("remove from set success set:{}", concurrentHashSet);
            log.info("execute task thread exit!");
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exeState);
            assert process != null;
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: best practice in product environment!!!!!!!
jump into anthor server to exec command